# How to verify data dumps between two MS SQL and MySQL

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-2008, mysql-5.5

I'm trying to verify data exported from MSSQL and imported into MySQL is 100% accurate using MD5 hash. On Linux, I'm using md5sum and WinMD5 on Windows. The encoding is the same: UTF8. I tried both UNICODE and ANSI, but the results were the same.

When I visually compare the data in the export files or the hashes of individual cell values, it's 100% accurate. However, comparing the two files results in different hashes.  Anyone know why the hashes would be different?

Your comments are much appreciated.

UPDATE:
The data is exported from MSSQL using BCP into a text (.txt) file. MySQL data is exported using: SELECT * INTO OUTFILE.... into a text file. Both use "%^&" as the field delimiter,"!@#$" as the row delimter, and escape using "\".

Comment: What files?  How were they exported?  For starters, the line separators consist of 2 chars on Windows and only one on Linux if you are exporting a csv or some other text file.

Comment: @Max - I added the information you requested. I'm not clear on line separators using 2 char vs. 1 char. I chose to separate them using something other than the default newline/return character.  - Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

There can be various reasons why file hashes different:

- Line Endings differ;
- Spacing might differ (tabs vs spaces);
- Different layout for same data
- Encoding (of the file that data is saved in)
- Quotes (single vs double)
- Case sensitivity

What I would do, is compare both files with `diff` tool. `git diff` can come in help here as it has ability to diff word by word and if you pass it `--no-index` option don't even have to place them in git repository. This command can help

```
$ git diff --no-index --color-words file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the [comp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490883.aspx) command to find out the first place they're different.

Then open the files up in a hex editor, like [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) for Windows, and look at where they're different.  In particular, look for:

- CRLF (DOS, 0x0D0A) vs LF (*nix, 0x0A) line termination
- Unicode [BOM (Byte Order Mark, UTF-8 being  0xEFBBBF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of one but not the other
- fancy quotes vs. regular quotes
- case issues